# Focus on an element Selenium

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have a screen that contains a set of filters which are displayed when pressing a specific key. I need to automate the selection of these filters.

Each filter has an Xpath which points to an html element that contains a text. I have tried the following:

```
private List<WebElement> elements;

public void reloadFilters() {
    String FilterXPath = this.FILTER_ITEM_XPATH;
    elements = webDriver.findElements(By.xpath(FilterXPath));   
}
```

and then

```
public void selectFilter(String filter) {
    WebElement W;
    Iterator I = elements.iterator();
    if (I.hasNext()) {
        W = (WebElement)I;
        if (W.getText().equals(filter)) {
            new Actions(webDriver).moveToElement(W).perform();
        }
    }
}
```

But I when I run this code I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList$Itr cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
```

Any suggestion on how can I perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change;

```
W=(WebElement)I;
```

to

```
W=(WebElement)I.next();
```

also, use proper variable names;

```
public void selectFilter(String filter) {
    Iterator iter = elements.iterator();
    if (iter.hasNext()) {
        WebElement element = (WebElement)iter.next();
        if (element.getText().equals(filter))
        {
            new Actions(webDriver).moveToElement(element).perform();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It would also help to generify the `Iterator`.